# Uncheck other Checkboxes if one is checked as true

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a sheet with 3 form control Checkboxes not ActiveX (Check Box 16 , Check Box 17 & Check Box 18) and all of them are linked to cells - and because thery are linked to their cells I can't use IF function to turn other Check boxes to false if one is ture.... please I need your help  to slove this problem if there is one Check Box is checkded as true, the other two check boxes to be unchecked

Comment: Use VBA code to do exactly what you need

Comment: @Foxfire - actually I have tried some of codes from internet but not working with me and I dont know how to create special code for my case

Comment: Have a look to `Option Button`

Comment: Usually, you would use Option Buttons (RadioButtons) rather than CheckBoxes for that - Option Buttons have already the build-in functionality that only one of them can be selected.

Comment: Thanks @Black cat and FunThomas ... i know but in my sheet for some wrok purposes I need it to be checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you really need Checkboxes, you need to react on the change event.

In a regular VBA module, add the following code (note that this works only for Form Controls)

```
Sub Checkbox_Click()
    HandleCheckboxGroup Application.caller, Array("Check Box 16", "Check Box 17", "Check Box 18")
End Sub

Sub HandleCheckboxGroup(caller, checkBoxList)
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim currentCheckBox As CheckBox
        Set currentCheckBox = .Shapes(caller).OLEFormat.Object
        
        If currentCheckBox.Value <> xlOn Then Exit Sub    ' Not check, nothing to do.
        Dim checkBoxName
        For Each checkBoxName In checkBoxList
            If caller <> checkBoxName Then
                .Shapes(checkBoxName).OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOff
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Assign the macro `Checkbox_Click` to all of your checkboxes. Have a closer look to the names in the checkbox array in that routine and adapt it if you have different checkbox names (if I were you, I would give them more meaningful names).

`Application.Caller` will tell which checkbox called `Checkbox_Click` (it's a string giving the name). This name is passed to `HandleCheckboxGroup` together with an array of checkboxes that a handled together (you could have another group of checkboxes that is handled similarly).

`HandleCheckboxGroup` will first check if the current CheckBox was checked (if it was unchecked, there is nothing to do). To get the real CheckBox object, you need to find the shape with the name of the checkbox (the *Caller*). For that shape, use the property `OLEFormat.Object` to get the checkbox object.

Now the routine will loop over all checkbox names of the group. If the name is different from the caller, it will reset the value (to `xlOff`).

**Update**
When grouping the checkboxes, you need to change the code. Grouped shapes are not part of the `Shapes` collection of a worksheet (only the group itself is), instead, you can access the shapes of a group via the property `GroupItems`. Unfortunately, the shapes of `GroupItems` cannot be accessed via name, only via index. Therefore we need to loop twice over them.

The event handler routine now passes the name of the group - **set this to the name of your group**.

```
Sub Checkbox_Click()
    HandleCheckboxes Application.caller, "Group 4"
End Sub


Sub HandleCheckboxes(caller, groupName)
    Dim group As Shape
    Set group = ActiveSheet.Shapes(groupName)
        
    Dim sh As Shape
    
    ' First loop: Find the current checkbox within group
    For Each sh In group.GroupItems
        If sh.Name = caller Then
            Dim currentCheckBox As CheckBox
            Set currentCheckBox = sh.OLEFormat.Object
            If currentCheckBox.Value <> xlOn Then Exit Sub  ' Nothing to do
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ' Second loop: Reset all other checkboxes within group                   
    For Each sh In group.GroupItems
        If sh.Name <> caller And sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
            sh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOff
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas - actually the code gives me runtime error (the item with the specified name was not found) - FYI - my checkboxes were not grouped and now i grouped them (Group 8) but still the same error - my sheet is named (Permit) and it has other codes... do i have to change the name is code to permit instead of activesheet? or what should  I do?

Comment: When you group shapes, they can no longer be found in the `Shapes`-collection of the worksheet, this is the reason you get the "name not found"-error. I have adapted the code to handle grouped checkboxes. Using `ActiveSheet` is not the issue here because you can click on a checkbox only if it is active - but of course you could use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Permit")` instead.

Comment: Sorry but still not working - now I only changed (Group 4) in the code to (Group 8) and changed (groupname) to (Group8) but i got a different error ("the index into the specified collection is out of bounds")

Comment: Strange. Only change the name of `Group 4` to `Group 8`.  Which line throws the error?

Comment: THIS LINE:  Set group = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Group8)   and even before change groupname (Set group = ActiveSheet.Shapes(groupName)

Comment: The call in  `CheckBox_Click` needs to be `HandleCheckboxes Application.caller, "Group 8"` - don't forget the double quotes. The assignment in `HandleCheckboxes` is `Set group = ActiveSheet.Shapes(groupName)` - the groupname is passed as parameter. If it still fails, the name of your group is likely wrong

Comment: my group name is "Group 8" - and now I got new error (Type mismatch) this line :    If sh.Name = caller Then

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot debug the code for you. What is the content of `caller` when that happens? How was the code triggered?